# 'strace vim/nano' (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I was experimenting with strace, having read about it in a book.

I tried to give it strange input, so I tried giving nano/vim as input. e.g.

```
strace vim
```

I noticed that the output was highly peculiar in both instances.

Once running, any subsequent action involving the keyboard and mouse shows strace output dynamically within the terminal, but has really strange format:

```
[0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)                                                                                                 select(1select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeosesselect(1, [0select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)lect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)                                                                                                 select(1select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeosesselect(1, [0fsync(3)                                = 0eout)ut)t(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)lect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)                                                                                                 select(1select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timselect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)eout)ut)t(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)lect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
                                     select(1select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timselect(1, [0], [], [0], NULL {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ut)t(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)lect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
                                                                                                 select(1select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeosesselect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ut)t(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)                                                                                                  select(1select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeosesselect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ut)t(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)                                                                                                  write(1,select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeosesselect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ut)t(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)te(1, "\33[?25lt\33[25;267H5\33[1;25H\33[?25h", 30t                                                                                             6
    select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeosesselect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ut)(1, "\33[?25le\33[25;267H7\33[1;27H\33[?25h", 30e                                                                                          7
                                                                select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeosesselect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ut)                                                                               8
-- INSERT --                                                                                                                                                                         sesselect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ut)                1,2           All) = 58                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            sesselect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)ut)], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
                    sewselect(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)fsdgaeeeaeeec=0, teteaeteae) = 0 (Timeout)
                                                                                wriwrite(1, "\33[?25lqhdfffsdgaeee\33[11Cteae\33[25"..., 50qhdfffsdgaeee_sec=0, teateae=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
                                                                                                                                                                                         select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
                        select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
                                                                                    write(1, "\33[1;2H\33[?25h", 12                                                                                                                                                      7
```

Upon keymashing to try to perform a write operation within vim, amongst the output shown in the terminal was strace output pertaining to the miscellaneous characters that I typed, see:

```
 wriwrite(1, "\33[?25lqhdfffsdgaeee\33[11Cteae\33[25"..., 50qhdfffsdgaeee_sec=0, teateae=0}) = 0
```

can anyone explain why the output is so strange when running:

```
strace nano
```

or

```
strace vim
```

?

Namely why the output in terminal is updated whenever a button is pressed on the keyboard or mouse, or whenever a scroll operation is performed with the mouse? Could anyone specifically explain how strace interacting with vim in this instance from an I/O perspective?

Comment: What exactly is strange? What miscellaneous characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're tracing an application that is trying to control the window at the same time strace is logging to that window. Instead, try this:

In window 1, run:

```
strace -o $HOME/tracefile vim
```

In window 2, run:

```
tail -f $HOME/tracefile
```

You can interact with vim in window 1 and see what calls vim is making in window 2.
When you're done, <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> in window 2 will stop the tail.